# не могу отключить верификацию в Yii 1.x

Tags: php, yii

```
array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => '/base/base/captcha', 'message' => 'Неверный проверочный код.')
```

ставлю вот так:

```
  array('verifyCode', 'safe')
```

сайт перестает работать. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону мне смотреть. 
*p.s. хочу отключить CAPTCHA полностью и подключить reCAPTCHA*

Comment: Заметил одну вещь, когда что-нибудь меняю в модули, сайт ломается. `array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => '/base/base/captcha', 'message' => 'ДАЖЕ КОДА МЕНЯЮ ТУТ.')`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в след. открывал через обычный блокнот, при сохранении кодировка менялась. Начал открывать и редактировать через phpStorm и всё получилось.